# What is strlen actually doing?

Tags: fortran

This is subroutine strlen

```
      subroutine strlen(string,i1,i2)
      character string*(*)
      do 10 i=len(string),1,-1
        if(string(i:i).ne.' ')then
          i2=i
          goto 11
        endif
   10   continue
   11 do 20 i=1,len(string)
        if(string(i:i).ne.' ')then
          i1=i
          return
        endif
   20   continue
      return
      end
```

In the main

```
 if(nfil.lt.0)then
    call strlen(cpar,i1,i2)
    open(unit=10,file=cpar(i1:i2),status='old')
```

If cpar is declared
      character cpar*(*)

Does it exist any rule or limitation regarding the name of the cpar to be openned properly?

My hx263on.sens(cpar) can not be read.Why?

Comment: In the main program `cpar` will need a declaration beyond `cpar*(*)`.  Can you find that?

Comment: Is cpar equal to "hx263on.sens(cpar)" or to "hx263on.sens" or to what actually? How long it is? How you tried to print it?

Comment: @VladimirF No,actually I have named file hx263on.sens.I use this file as input file but can not read it.

Comment: `hx263on.sens.I` is not the same as `hx263on.sens(cpar)` nor `hx263on.sens`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function just looks for the first and the last character which is not a space. These are returned as `i1` and `i2`. `cpar(i1:i2)` should be the same as `adjustl(trim(cpar))` from Fortran 90.

This should not be necessary. Fortran trims file names passed to open anyway. File-names ending with spaces are not supported.

If the file cannot be opened, it probably does not exist or contains some special characters which the operating system does not like. Or it actually contains something else than you think. Maybe the variable is too short or something like that. Verify the value of `cpar` and `cpar(i1:i2)` by printing it.

Comment: That does not really matter.